# How can I get all pointer class value Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two table Order and Modifiers. Modifier is the pointer class for the Order. Modifiers has a column (name ,price etc). I want to get all the values of Modifiers with order.

**Code**

```
PFQuery *queryLocal= [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"order"];
[queryLocal whereKey:@"order_no" equalTo:orderno];
[queryLocal includeKey:@"modifiers"];
[queryLocal fromLocalDatastore];
[queryLocal findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (block) {
        block(objects,nil);
    }

}];
```

**Output :**

```
   <modifiers: 0x7a15dc30, objectId: ZgikpV86HB, localId: (null)> {
}
```

It gives me only the objectId. is there any way to get all values